# Javascript: Remove checked status from disabled input (already checked)

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Im trying to make this function to check an element and if its checked, or not, add or remove respective className. Also, if the element is disabled but is checked, it should un-check it and remove the className('yes')

```
function init() {
    $(document.body).select('input').each(function(element) {
        if (!element.checked) {
            element.up().removeClassName('yes');
        } else {
            element.up().addClassName('yes');
        }
        if (element.checked && element.disabled) {
            element.checked = false;
            element.up().removeClassName('yes')
        }
    });

}
```

Right now, the last part, is not working, no effect

Comment: Is `element.checked && element.disabled` returning `true`? (Are you entering the final `if` block?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `element.checked = !element.checked` in the last part instead of `element.checked = false`?

Comment: This works, but I have problems to make it work from the document load:

Im using this source to make it work: